# VPN bridge duplicate routes

Tags: linux, openvpn, bridge

I'm trying to establish a VPN bridge between 2 embedded computers. VPN gets established correctly, however once tap0 interface gets created on the client's side, it creates a duplicate route:

```
192.168.127.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap0
192.168.127.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

here are the configuration of both interfaces:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:e8:44:76:1c
          inet addr:192.168.127.20  Bcast:192.168.127.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::290:e8ff:fe44:761c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING ALLMULTI MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1578 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:141027 (137.7 KiB)  TX bytes:8351 (8.1 KiB)

tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a6:ed:36:87:50:12
          inet addr:192.168.127.50  Bcast:192.168.127.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a4ed:36ff:fe87:5012/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:1380 (1.3 KiB)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)
```

What I'm trying to do is route traffic of devices connected to the client (in the same subnet as the client) to the server and eventually to a PC connected to the server. The server has the IP address `192.168.127.10` and the PC connected to it `192.168.127.200`

With the current routing table, the server is unable to ping the client and vice versa.

**Attempts to resolve the issue**

1. If I remove the eth0 route:

   `192.168.127.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     5      0        0 tap0`

   ```
   Ping Client's tap0 --> Server's tap0 : OK
   Ping Server's tap0 --> Client's tap0 : OK
   Ping Client's tap0 --> PC connected to server : OK
   Ping PC connected to server --> PC connected to client : FAIL
   Ping PC connected to server --> Client's tap0 : OK
   Ping PC connected to client --> Client's tap0 : FAIL
   Ping PC connected to client --> Server's tap0 : FAIL
   Ping PC connected to client --> PC connected to Server : FAIL
   ```
2. Since the client is only supposed to reach 2 IP addresses on the server side, let's add static routes to these IPs & let normal traffic be handled by eth0:

`192.168.127.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     5      0        0 eth0
192.168.127.10  *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tap0
192.168.127.200 *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tap0`

notice the route priority!

```
Ping Client's tap0 --> Server's tap0 : FAIL
Ping Server's tap0 --> Client's tap0 : FAIL
Ping Client's tap0 --> PC connected to server : FAIL
Ping PC connected to server --> PC connected to client : FAIL
Ping PC connected to server --> Client's tap0 : FAIL
Ping PC connected to client --> Client's tap0 : OK
Ping PC connected to client --> Server's tap0 : FAIL
Ping PC connected to client --> PC connected to Server : FAIL
```

**Any idea how to set up the routing table in my case?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I ended up simply bridging eth0 with tap0 on the client. This united both initial routes into a single route pointing to br0. 
Unlike the server, the interface bridging on the client's side must take place after the openvpn connection has been established!